# Function showing mysterious behaviors

Tags: java-8, kotlin

I am developing an android application with `kotlin` assistance but the question is based on pure `kotlin` fundamentals. Below is the function which is showing some unusual behavior:

```
fun CatchThat(funct: () -> Unit){
try {
    funct()
}catch (ex: Error){
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
}
```

When I use it in my code

```
CatchThat {
// Proprietary Code goes in here
}
```

- **Debugger does not work properly(sometimes)**
- **The proprietary code does not execute at all(sometimes)**

Why is that behavior encountered or am I getting some concepts wrong(maybe `lambdas`). Any help or suggestions are heartily welcomed.(I am a tyro in `kotlin`)

**EDIT** The thing that I am doing in **Proprietary code**.
I am trying to invoke a `Thread Pool` that is in turn calling a web activity. This is the best and all I could explain about it. I am sorry for that.

Comment: For me this code sample works... which version of kotlin are you using and what is the proprietary code you are providing?

Comment: You aren't getting any output ? you should replace Error with Throwable to catch Exceptions too

Comment: `Kotlin 1.1.2` and sorry I could not provide the Proprietary code as the code is **Proprietary**

Comment: No @crgarridos **sometimes** is important to note here.The same code is working at one point of time without error and goes blank the next time!!!

Comment: try to explain what are you doing in that code. The snippet is right. Launching another thread maybe ?

Comment: I have edited the question @crgarridos.Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it sorts out the problem but it's just worth a try since all your efforts went in vein(and also because there is no error in your syntax).
I guess if debugger stops on wrong line(or sometimes doesn't work), it usually means that
 **something broken in the code cache** .

> **Try invalidating Idea cache and restarting if you are using Idea of course.**

And before doing that

> **I would also recommend to update Kotlin with the latest version.**

Comment: Thanks Sir!! The first bold line doesn't worked but the last line i.e updating to the latest version i.e. `1.1.3` fixes the issue.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

try/catch will only work on the current thread. In your snippet, if some exception ocourrs in another thread, the try/catch won't work

For example:

```
try {
    println("Hola mundo 1!")
    println(5 / 0)
} catch (ex: Throwable) {
    println("Oups! $ex")// will be printed
}

try {
    Thread {
        println("Hola mundo 2!")
        println(5 / 0)
    }.start()
} catch (ex: Throwable) {
    println("Oups! $ex")// won't be printed
}

println("Hola mundo 3!")//The exception thrown in the external thread don't kill the current thread
```

For the debugging issues take a look to  [Android Studio threaded debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245411/android-studio-threaded-debugging)

Comment: Thanks a lot @crgarridos for the answer and giving your precious time for it but **why sometimes it gives the correct output, debugger works fine and sometimes the code executes too?**

Comment: Just guessing, it can variate for your code, as you have a thread pool, the execution is asynchronous. And then you can have exception in one or another thread "randomly"

Comment: Maybe! but thanks again for giving your precious time and +1 for that!!!!I will surely mention when I will get the correct fix

Comment: You're welcome, sorry for not be more clean but without the code is difficult to see the problem. I think you have somethings the output, but not all the code was well executed