# Why Android Studio debugger doesn't stop on code that is called inside runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging

I found this bug on with the following code:

```
(it.context.get() as? Activity)?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            it.weakRefIOnDataRefreshed.get()?.onDataRefreshed(refreshedItemList)
        })
```

The code above is inside  a *run* method that runs in a non UI Thread. I want to call a method in fragment with the refreshedItemList as argument. I want to debug the *onDataRefreshed* method (which is inside a Fragment), and I'm putting inside this function  a break point but nothing happens. I also put a *Log* method to make sure that the code is running and the Log method prints indeed. What may be the problem that the debugger doesn't stop on the line which I have marked?

Comment: Maybe try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29389601/1827254

Comment: @Eselfar thanks suddenly after two restarts it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In your class where that background thread works define a Handler object and use post method to update UI e.g. (Java).

```
// Define handler object
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper);
...
...

// Here ise where you want to update your UI
handler.post(() -> {
    // Your code with which you want to update the UI
}
```

Comment: What wrong the way I do it? And why the debugger ignores my request?

Comment: It is all about the way you implement your code. It is hard to say something just by seeing 2 lines of code. I don't have any idea about your code, you tell the problem but didn't share enough code to analyze.

Comment: thanks suddenly after two restarts it works :)